# Problems with lwarp and pstricks

Tags: pstricks, ghostscript, lwarp

My question is about packages `lwarp` and `pstricks`.
I use to work in `pstricks` for exercises sheets  and then converted to HTML page with a little help of `lwarp`. It worked perfectly.

Two days ago I upgraded my LaTeX distribution (MacTeX Latex 2021 for macOS 10.15.7 Catalina) and I found that I need to add `-dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY` in the line of `ps2pdf` (I use TexMaker). But the problem is when I try to pass `file.tex` to `file.html` as I used to do, I have a error message in terminal:

```
 Last OS error: No such file or directory
Current file position is 588453
GPL Ghostscript 9.53.3: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
```

And I have no idea how to fix it. Any help would be welcomed.

Comment: Hello every one. I have found a solution. I put \lwarpsetup{
 HTMLLatexCmd=
{
 latex --shell-escape \jobname_html \LWRopseq
 dvips -o \jobname_html.ps \jobname_html.dvi \LWRopseq
 ps2pdf -dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY \jobname_html.ps
}
} just under \usepackage[options]{lwarp} and it works. I don't Know if there is another one, in that case, please, write it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the `latex->dvips->ps2pdf`  route, you can run the PSTricks code with `lualatex`. Then you do not need GhostScript. Must have an up-to-date TeX 2021